# How to secure Class.forName("SimpleClass")?

Tags: java, security, checkmarx

I ran security scan on our application and one of the security issues that came up with is "Download of Code Without Integrity Check". This risk points of the line at `Class.forName("SimpleClass");`

how do I secure the above line of code?
How do I make sure the parameter for `forName("")` is not a malicious class that I would be loading.

Edit: Security Scan used is Checkmarx.

Comment: Please describe where the class is coming from. Understanding the full flow of the attack may help us better understand the situation and help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't get any classes from the outside, [this weakness](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/494.html) does not apply here. In this case you can load malicious class iff it is already on the classpath. Meaning the attacker already has access to the classpath - in this case resistance is futile.

If you do get classes from the outside - like, download them from somewhere or allow users to upload classes or source code and compile it - then you are subject to this weakness and need to take measures. If you get classes from users you have a problem. :) If you get them from some location you seem as secure, you can use HTTPS or check signatures on your own. But I guess this is not your case.

Comment: While the above downloading weakness is a possible issue with Class.forName, it is not the only one. Loading classes from the inside can also be dangerous, see https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/SEC52-J.+Do+not+expose+methods+that+use+reduced-security+checks+to+untrusted+code

Answer (score 1):

Don't put a jar containing untrusted classes in your classpath.

The message is incorrect. This won't download anything. It will just load a class that must already be in your classpath in order to be loaded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Class.forName("SimpleClass");`, you could create an enum that holds all of the classes that you would want to leverage based on that string. For example:

```
public enum InvokeableClasses {
    SOME_CLASS(SomeClass.class),
    ANOTHER_CLASS(AnotherClass.class),
    YET_ANOTHER_CLASS(YetAnotherClass.class),
    SIMPLE_CLASS(SimpleClass.class);

    private final Class clazz;
    InvokeableClasses(Class clazz){
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class getClazz() {
        return this.clazz;
    }

    public static InvokeableClasses fromString(String className) {
        for(InvokeableClasses currentInvokeableClass : InvokeableClasses.values()) {
            if(currentInvokeableClass.getClazz().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase(className)) {
                return currentInvokeableClass;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you utilize the enum instead of `Class.forName("SimpleClass");` like so:

```
InvokeableClasses.fromString("SimpleClass").getClazz();
```

I used a similar approach, opting for getCanonicalName() in lieu of getSimpleName() for assuring the class was from the expected package.

The drawback here is that you need to enumerate the possible classes before hand but it is much more secure.

I know this question is old but it felt like the answers were not completely satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

I think the alternative is to use an ad 'hoc' class.
Each thread in Java can have a Context Class Loader.
In my case with the same message in Checkmarx I created a class.

```
public static Class<?> forName(String className, ClassLoader classLoader) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if (classLoader == null) try {
        // Controlla il caricatore di classi del thread
        classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        if (classLoader != null) {
            return Class.forName(className, true, classLoader);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // non trovato, usa il caricatore della classe standard
        classLoader = null;
    }
    if (classLoader != null) {
        return Class.forName(className, true, classLoader);
    }
    return Class.forName(className);
}
```

}`
and recall it using:

```
Class<?> c1 = ContexClassLoader.forName(<StringOfClassName>,ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

So I DO NOT use Class.forName anymore and Checkmarx is satisfied.
Ciao.